# Closed form solution for the difference of two poisson processes

Tags: stochastic-processes, closed-form, poisson-process

I'm interested in whether there is a closed-form distribution of the time it takes two Poisson processes to output counts to have a fixed difference.  For example, let

$k_1$ ~ Poisson($\lambda_1t$)

$k_2$ ~ Poisson($\lambda_2t$)

Is there a closed-form solution for $p(t|k_1 - k_2 = n)$?

It's tricky because presumably that equality could happen multiple times while observing the processes.  I'm specifically looking for the *first* time.

I know that $k_1-k_2$ ~ Skellam($\lambda_1,\lambda_2$) but I can't work out  a distribution for time.